# Eliminate the last comma in curly braces using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to take out the last comma in curly braces using regex.  I have the following example:

```
cypher_query = 'match n:chocolate{chocolate:$chocolate, icecream:'snowcone', donut:$donut, chocolate:$chocolate,}) return n';
```

with the goal of getting (takes out that last comma in the curly braces):

```
cypher_query = 'match n:chocolate{chocolate:$chocolate, icecream:'snowcone', donut:$donut, chocolate:$chocolate}) return n';
```

Using regex, I've tried the following:

```
import re
new_query = re.sub(r'\{\,$\}', '', cypher_query)
```

Any ideas?? Thanks so much!

Comment: `cypher_query = cypher_query.replace(',}', '}')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the part starting from the `{` to before the comma in group 1.

Then match `,}` and replace with the group 1 value `\1` and only `}`

```
({[^{}]*),}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uMtvqg/1)

```
import re

cypher_query = 'match n:chocolate{chocolate:$chocolate, icecream:\'snowcone\', donut:$donut, chocolate:$chocolate,}) return n';
new_query = re.sub(r'({[^{}]*),}', r'\1}', cypher_query)
print(new_query)
```

Output

```
match n:chocolate{chocolate:$chocolate, icecream:'snowcone', donut:$donut, chocolate:$chocolate}) return n
```

Answer (score 1):

So this?

```py
import re
new_query = re.sub(',}', '}', cypher_query) #looks for ,} and replaces it with just a }
```